# How do I compare string in Ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml

How do I go about comparing strings? For example
"a" and "b", since "a" comes before "b" then I would put in a tuple like this`("a","b")`. For "c" and "b", it would be like this `("b","c")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compare strings with the usal comparison operators: `=`, `<>`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.

You can also use the `compare` function, which returns -1 if the first string is less than the second, 1 if the first string is greater than the second, and 0 if they are equal.

```
# "a" < "b";;
- : bool = true
# "a" > "b";;
- : bool = false
# compare "a" "b";;
- : int = -1
```

Comment: Since this is top result on a search engine, is there also a way to get the diff between two strings easily?