# How to compare the strings in OCaml?

Tags: string, compare, ocaml, string-comparison

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882374/how-do-i-compare-string-in-ocaml) and I had a try in utop.

My code is just: `"a" < "b"`

But there is an error that: Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type int.

[The code and the error in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTi0C.png)

Another code is:

```
(*
    Given a list of strings, check to see if it is ordered, i.e. whether earlier elements are less than or equal to later elements.
*)

let rec is_ordered (ls: string list): bool =
    match ls with
    | head::[] -> true
    | head1::(tail1::tail2) -> ((head1 <= tail1) && is_ordered(tail1::tail2))
    | _ -> false
```

And the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Style suggestion: use `as` to clean up your code. `head1::(tail1::tail2) -> ((head1 <= tail1) && is_ordered(tail1::tail2))` => `hd::(snd::_ as tl) -> head <= snd && is_ordered tl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using modules from Jane Street. The Jane Street modules redefine the polymorphic comparison operators (like `<`) so that they operate only on ints.

Here is a recent discussion: [Question About OCaml Function Signatures in UTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764266/question-about-ocaml-function-signatures-in-utop/73764460?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C65.2831#73764460)

If you want to keep using the Jane Street modules you can use `String.compare` to compare strings.

Comment: At this point it feels like these questions should really be dealt with by being closed as duplicates.